# Unable to Read file in C

Tags: c, file-io

I am a beginner at C and am using DevC++. I have written the code below and wish to read in the data written in input.txt. However when I try to run the code, I always receive the "Cant open file" message. It seems unable to find input.txt, and I am entirely unsure how to change that.

```
int T;
char command;
FILE *inputfile;

inputfile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

if(inputfile == NULL)
{
    printf("Cant open file");
}

fscanf(inputfile, "%d", &T);
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of the following reasons

1. File you are reading and your source code are not in same directory
2. You have misspelled the file name

Otherwise your code is correct there should be no problem

Comment: Largely correct, but for 1 it is more relevant from which directory the executable is working than where the source code is.